# How do I hide only half of an image with a script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

I have an img on the page with class `.ff-og-image-inserted`. I need a script to insert an other class .container-closed to hide part of this image with class `.ff-og-image-inserted`

**What i've tried:**

```js
$(".ff-og-image-inserted").addClass("container-closed");
```

```css
.ff-og-image-inserted {
  overflow: auto;
  height: auto;
}

.ff-og-image-inserted>container-closed {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 470px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div><img src="link.jpg" class="ff-og-image-inserted" /></div>
```

**My question:**
Why this code is not working? I understand that there might be other solutions but i really need to know first of all why this solution is not working so please suggestions related to this solution and not other solutions.

More info: i can see that the image gets the class `.container-closed` but the css is not applied at all. I want to add class to the image itself because the parent div of the image has no class or id and i can't change that since these are automated posted images.

[image]

Thnx

Comment: You're missing the `.` before `container-closed` in the CSS; but we'd need to see the HTML on which the CSS applies to understand the question better...

Comment: I added html on which css is applied.

Comment: Yeah, so, the answer is correct, the `>` selector is the wrong one; you want elements that have both classes applied to the same element. I'm not sure why you can add classes to the image, but not its parent `div`; just use `$(".ff-og-image-inserted").parent().addClass("container-closed");`...

Comment: Can you check the image please attached to the question. I tried both with parent and direct image class and also corrected selector > with . but css is not applying even though i see the class in parent div.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works with parent div class. I was leaving the old css where .container-closed was part of the image itself. If you put it as answer i would vote as solution.

Comment: If @rsn's answer works for you, that's fine. They need the rep more than me :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `>` selector, which means 'direct descendent ([reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp))' :

```
.ff-og-image-inserted > container-closed {
```

It should simply be:

```
.ff-og-image-inserted.container-closed {
```

As you want to apply the `overflow` attribute to the parent container, not the image itself.

//

What OP wanted was add a class to the `img`'s parent instead:

```
$('.ff-og-image-inserted').parent().addClass('container-closed');
```

Comment: Hi. Thnx for your answer. There is no parent container. I want to apply to the image itself. Or better, there is a parent div but it has no class or id and i can't change that since these are automated posted images.

Comment: 'Cropping' the image using `overflow` will only work if the image is inside a container. for instance, change your `<script>` to `$(".ff-og-image-inserted").parent().addClass("container-closed");` instead.